# I got the c# form error and now I can't see any of my objects in my form

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I got that error that I think we all have gotten before, for example, if you deleted the `button1_Click` event you would get an error, being me, I accidentally clicked continue or something and now **NONE** of the things in my form show up and I'm stuck with the starter `form1` but my program still works, I've tried Ctrl+Z and all of that. Still, it didn't work. Is there any way to get back my form?

Comment: Right click on your project in project structure on the left. then Local History -> Show History

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Alt+Up` and `Alt+Down` perhaps then or search for local history. If it doesn't work install *Local History for Visual Studio* it's a plugin.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the Project Structure you're talking about, is there a way  I can view it in "View" (I am sorry I am new to visual studio)

Comment: Never mind, I found out what you are talking about, but when I right click it, Local History is not there.

Comment: Thanks! I rolled back to where I didn't get the error!